# Slicing an immutable string state based on an increment state while displaying state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have this simplified structure of my issue here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/continous-text-mirror-state-break-line-xqvu46?file=/src/App.tsx)

It consists of a `useGenText()` hook, which simulates generating word every nth seconds, and the value is read-only, so **can not modify this hook**. The `useLineIndex()` hook simulates the increasing of the active line in every mth seconds, also have set method to increase and decrease it.

I want it to display the words and move to new line every time `lineIndex` is updated. And on the newline, I want it to show the continue text of the previous line. With the code below, it always shows the whole text of the previous line as well.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const updatedLines = [...lines];
    updatedLines[currentLineIndex] = transcript;
    setLines(updatedLines);
}, [transcript, currentLineIndex]);
...
//Output:
-burned house stone stone bird
-burned house stone stone bird stone shopping cart flying stone stone stone

//Desired Output:
-burned house stone stone bird
-stone shopping cart flying stone stone stone
```

How can I achieve such desired behavior? I also thought of copy transcript to a new state and `.slice()`, but don't get the data on where the break new line happened in the string, and how to update to the new line string, while subscribing to the transcript content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current `length` of the `transcript` in a ref. Whenever the `transcript` or the `currentLineIndex` changes, slice all the text from the ref forwards, and add it to the current line. Update the ref in another `useEffect` block whenever the `transcript` changes. Use an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters) to create a new state based on the previous value ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/continous-text-mirror-state-break-line-forked-6hcrou)):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const length = len.current;

  setLines((prev) => {
    const updatedLines = [...prev];

    const val = updatedLines[currentLineIndex] ? ? '';

    updatedLines[currentLineIndex] = `${val} ${transcript.slice(length)}`.trim();

    return updatedLines;
  });
}, [transcript, currentLineIndex]);

useEffect(() => {
  len.current = transcript.length;
}, [transcript]);
```